# Bootstrap tables only displaying one row in <td>

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Table Error]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/me2X3.jpg)

As you can see from the image the first row from the table is only in the actual table. It could be code error I'm not sure?

```
$selectNews = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `news`");

echo '<table class="table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<th>Update Number</th>';
    echo '<th>Title</th>';
    echo '<th>Description</th>';
    echo '<th>Created On</th>';
    echo '<th>Created By</th>';
    echo '</thead>';

while ($results = $selectNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $results['ID']."</td><td>";
echo $results['Title']."</td><td>";
echo $results['Description']."</td><td>";
echo date('d/m/Y g:i:s A',  strtotime($results['Time']))."</td><td>";   
echo $results['Creater']."</td></tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check, if `$selectNews` is really valid. From [`PDO::query`](http://de3.php.net/pdo.query)

> **Return Values**
>   **PDO::query()** returns a PDOStatement object, or **FALSE** on failure.

*Update:*

You have put `tbody` and `table` inside your while loop. You must put the opening and closing tags outside

```
echo "<tbody>";
while ($results = $selectNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    ...
    echo $results['Creater']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It's showing all the rows in the DB as you can see in the image, however the second row is not in the table when I have clearly put it in a while loop.